# odata - disable paging in custom provider

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I have created an OData wrapper layer to my existing data engine. All operations including: sorting filtering and paging are passed directly to my existing engine and retrieve the needed data.

problem is with the paging: second page results are retrieved from my existing engine, but later odata skips the amount of "skip=" and sends empty collection to the client. for example:
I am paging "Products", there are 100 in the DB. First page gets 10 to the server, skips 0 and sends the 10 to the client. second page gets 10 to the server, skips 10 and sends nothing to the customer.

Is there a way around this?

p.s.
Page size my vary according to client request. I cannot write it hardcoded on the server.

Comment: Could you please post the URL queries for the first and second page? Also the expression tree executed against your provider for these queries would help as well.

Comment: first page query:/Products?&$orderby=product_id asc&$top=10
second page query: /Products?&$orderby=product_id asc&$top=10&$skip=10

Comment: That looks correct (From the client perspective). So you're saying that even if the query has $skip=10, WCF DS actually skips over 100 rows? Could you please check what is the query (LINQ expression tree) executed against your custom provider for the second query?

Comment: No, It skips 10. but after I retrieved records 11-20 all I have to in my server is 10 records, and they are skipped... I will try to get a string out of the expression when debugging.

Comment: I am trying to get something out of System.Linq.Expressions.Expression that I can post here, but not sure where to look as it seems very complex . so my real question here is - how do I read System.Linq.Expressions.Expression and how do I change it to remove the "skip" part

Comment: The Expression class (in .NET 4.0) has two ways to get the content in a readable way. One is the ToString method, in the debugger this should be the default visualization anyway. Second, there should be a property on it with Debug word in the name. The value of that is a human-readable version of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this method call in my code and added the first 2 lines:

```
public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression.ToString().Contains(".Skip("))
            expression = (expression as MethodCallExpression).Arguments[0];

        return new DSPLinqQuery<TElement>(this, expression);
    }
```

this way the larger expression being built will not contain skip(10)

Comment: Maybe I'm getting confused. If you remove the Skip method (and please don't use the ToString to check for that, better way is to look at the name of the method on the MethodCallExpression), then the query will not contain Skip in it at all. So how do you make it skip the first 10 (or whatever number the client asked for)? Does this mean that your server "removes" the items already reported to the client from the returned collection?

Comment: No, my server gets the correct data from the DB (sorted filtered ad paged) OnStartProcessingRequest. LINQ runs later and does not affect the data. Filters and paging are taken directly from url to supply my  server with instructions of what to retreive. you are right about the tostring()

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know enough about your code to be able to tell where it's going wrong. If you confirm that the expression executed against the provider contains the right Skip call (as it seems to be the case), then there has to be something wrong in the interaction of your custom provider and LINQ. WCF DS on its own will not skip over data rows, it relies on the LINQ provider to do this due to the Skip call.